# Smooth line chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I have tried methods to smooth a line chart in Python, which was not difficult to achieve by making an interpolation, For example, with these datasets I am able to produce this chart.

`x =  np.linspace(0, 6, num=7)`, `A = [3, 4, 5, 3.5, 4.7, 5, 3.6]` and `B = [3.4, 4.2, 4.9, 3.7, 4.7, 4.2, 4.6]`

[image]

Although I did not like much the achieved effect, the reason is that for example between 2017-01-22 and 2017-01-23 it is assumed that B went down and then went up, I would like that 2 continous points to be connected in an increasing or decreasing way only, that is, that B appears smoothly growing in the 2017-01-21 and 2017-01-22 range.

Or more mathematically, **I would like the slope of the curve between 2 adjacent points to be only positive, negative or zero.**

How can I achieve the desired effect?

This is the code I'm using until now

```
def generate_graph():
    x =  np.linspace(0, 6, num=7)
    A = [3, 4, 5, 3.5, 4.7, 5, 3.6]
    B = [3.4, 4.2, 4.9, 3.7, 4.7, 4.2, 4.6]

    A_tck = splrep(x, A)
    A_average_tck = splrep(x, B)

    dates = [datetime.date.today() - timedelta(6), datetime.date.today() - timedelta(5), datetime.date.today() - timedelta(4), datetime.date.today() - timedelta(3), datetime.date.today() - timedelta(2), datetime.date.today() - timedelta(1), datetime.date.today()]

    x_new = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
    A_new = splev(x_new, A_tck)
    B_new = splev(x_new, A_average_tck)

    plt.plot(x_new, A_new, label='A')
    plt.plot(x_new, B_new, label='B')

    plt.xticks(x, dates, size='small')

    plt.grid()

    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.xlabel('X')

    plt.legend(loc='best')

    plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Use some monotonic interpolator, e.g. [Pchip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator)

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!

Comment: @sascha Using `PchipInterpolator` is a good idea. Would you like to provide this as an answer?

Comment: @OiciTrap does not add the answer to the question. Put it on as a answer!

Comment: @lbellomo But it's sasha's answer

Comment: @OiciTrap Please post it as a separate answer and provide credits to sascha